# How do I max out the triangle gauges in the top right corner of the screen?

Tags: doom-2016

I figured out that my missing triangle on the mission select screen is because I didn't max out all of my triangles. I see that they increase as I get kills and secrets, but is it a matter of finishing everything in the map, or do I need to do glory kills to get special progress towards completion? 
[image: Foundry]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the "Combat Rating". The codex page says that killing "as many demons as possible", the rating will increase and award Weapon Upgrade Points.

Comment: I notice that they seem to correlate with the number of the demons on the level. So killing all the demons on the level should yield all the weapon upgrade points for that level. But I may be wrong :)